# git clone repo to a remote machine

Tags: git

How do we clone a repo which is in the local directory to a remote mchine directory

```
 machine1:/usr/rep/  -> clone this to machine2:/var/new_repo
```

what is the actual command for this

`EDIT1`
I am trying to create the clone from machine1

`EDIT2`
I have also tried the following `git clone --bare user@anothersite.com/usr/repo /var/repo/` not sure whether its the right way to do it

`EDIT3`
This is the error after executing the command in EDIT2

```
You have no controlling tty and no DISPLAY. Cannot read passphrase. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly 

================================================Initialized empty Git repository
in /var/repo/ DEBUG: remote_exec loop:$stderr: Initialized empty Git repository
in /var/repo/ DEBUG: create_repoX loop: $stdout: DEBUG: create_repoX loop: 
$stderr: Initialized empty Git repository in /var/repo/ DEBUG: create_repoX loop: $exit: 32768
```

Comment: How do you provide access? Push (server is remote) or pull (server is local)?

Comment: @Reactormonk well you have heard of `sftpserver` and friends? A number of "servers" will happily use standard I/O redirection _via_ an SSH connection to achieve something like this. The only real prerequisite should be to have `git` installed on the remote machine (well and `sshd`). But then, this is Git ... simple things aren't simple and complex things not always possible either.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are legitimate reasons for 'pushing' a clone to a remote machine as opposed to running the clone on the remote machine itself, which I don't see covered by the other answers here. In fact, I have had reason to do this a number of times.

I wrote a script to handle it easily: [git-pushclone](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robertmuil/muiltools/master/bin/git-pushclone)

Description:
The script clones a repository **to** a remote server
and makes this new repository a remote
repository of the current one. SSH protocol is used.

This implements a push-style of cloning, which is necessary whenever
one does not want to clone from the remote machine. Examples are:

1. No incoming access to local server:
   When development has occurred on a local machine to which one does not wish to grant any remote access, but it is desired to 'publish' the development to a server from which others can then get access.
2. A communal login to remote server:
   When one does not have individual access to the remote server but can only login as a group user: in this case, initiating a clone from the remote server would require putting credentials for the local repository server in the group account of the server.

Comment: Strange assumption you make about machine1 being accessible from machine2 via SSH.

Comment: No such assumption is made. In fact, the situation in which machine1 is not accessible from machine2 is exactly where this script is useful. If machine1 were accessible, one could simply do a standard clone.

Comment: But as far as I see, you are not using `git push` to upload the cloned files to the new server, but using ssh and scp. So this wouldn't be a push-clone, but a scp-clone...

Answer (score 1):

Pass the command to `ssh` and clone the repository *from* machine2

```
ssh machine2 'git clone machine1:/path/to/repo /local/path/to/new/repo'
```

You need a ssh-server on machine1. However, you can even just copy the whole folder, because in git the repository is just a folder, thus copying it, will copy the repository.

```
scp -r /path/to/repo machine2:/var/new_repo
```

Comment: In the first option, `machine1` will need to have access to `machine2` and that's not always possible. even though from `machine2` there's access to `machine1`

Answer (score 0):

`git clone ssh://user@anothersite.com/usr/repo /var/repo/`

I mean `ssh user@host "git clone ssh://user@anothersite.com/usr/repo /var/repo/"`

Comment: I tried that earlier as indicated but i have mentioned the error any idea why

Comment: In Atlassian site it's written that we can git clone from local machine to remote machine (via http, ssh, etc) but should i do that on the commandline of the remote machine (i.e. gitlab server)? or on my local machine? if i do on my local machine, it's exactly the same command as when i clone from remote to local. how does git understand what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have SSH access to either the origin git server or the target git server, these are the commands you should carry out:

1. Check out the repository from your existing git host. Use the --mirror parameter:

   ```sh
   git clone --mirror <source-git-url> temp-dir
   ```
2. Add the corresponding new repo as another remote in your local repository:

   ```sh
   cd temp-dir
   git remote add newrepo <target-git-url>
   ```
3. Push the whole repo to the new location :

   ```sh
   git push --mirror newrepo
   ```
4. Remove your temporary local repository:

   ```sh
   cd ..
   rm -rf temp-dir
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You don't. You run `git clone` on the remote machine and clone from machine1. If that's not possible, simply clone it locally on machine 1 and copy the whole folder to machine2.

Comment: :I have tried the following but doesnt seem to work ,any ideas why ssh site.com "git clone --bare https://user@anothersite.com/usr/repo/ /var/repo/"

Comment: You have no controlling tty and no DISPLAY.  Cannot read passphrase.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
================================================Initialized empty Git repository in /var/repo/
DEBUG: remote_exec loop:$stderr: Initialized empty Git repository in /var/repo/

DEBUG: create_repoX loop: $stdout:
DEBUG: create_repoX loop: $stderr: Initialized empty Git repository in /var/repo/

DEBUG: create_repoX loop: $exit:   32768